# What is the domain of $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why is the domain for $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{x}}$, $[0,4]$?

$2-\sqrt{x}\ge 0$

This gives one $\sqrt{x}\ge 2$ or $x\ge 4$.

Why is the domain $ [0,4]$? Please explain as if I am a $5$ year old.

Comment: The inner root requires $x\geq 0$. The outer root requires $2-\sqrt{x} \geq 0$, which is equivalent to $\sqrt{x}\leq 2$, which is in turn equivalent to $x\leq 4$. Together, the logical "and" of these conditions is $0\leq x \leq 4$, *i.e.*, $x\in[0,4]$. Is that clear to you?

Answer (score 4):

Just to answer regarding your work:

> $(1)\;\;2-\sqrt{x}\ge 0$
>
> $(2)\;\;$This gives one $\sqrt{x}\ge 2$ or $x\ge 4$. **(Error)**

Your second step is mistaken. You forgot to change the direction of the inequality when moving from $(1)$ to $(2)$.

Starting with $(1)$:
$$2 -\sqrt x \geq 0 \iff 2 \geq \sqrt x \iff \sqrt x \leq 2 \implies x \le 4$$

Now, we also need $x \geq 0$, or else the inner square root: $\sqrt x$ will not be defined. So together, we have $x \geq 0, x \leq 4 \implies $ the domain of the function is $[0, 4]$.

Now

Comment: Ok this makes a little bit more sense to me. Is the inner root always towards the right? Is there an order of operations?

Comment: Is there a way I can practice this concept on line? My book is not clear about this.

Comment: The argument of a root with even index (such as a square root) must always be positive (when you want a real result), that's why we have the 2 conditions $(2-\sqrt{x}\ge0)\land (\sqrt{x}\ge0)$

Comment: The inner root is the "nested" root: the root inside of the root, so to speak. $\sqrt{\sqrt a + b}$: $a$ is the "argument" of the inner root, and $\sqrt a + b$ is the argument of the outer square root.

Comment: Your reasoning was fine, except for forgetting to switch the direction of the inequality, and forgetting to note that $x \geq 0$ in order for $\sqrt x$ to be defined. We simply need to be mindful, for example, in my example immediately above (comment), that we have $a\geq 0$, and $\sqrt a + b \geq 0$.

Comment: Using this example..I would evaluate the square root of a + b by setting it greater or equal to zero; thus, a is greater or equal to - (minus) b. Is there any further steps I would take after that?

Comment: We'd need $a \geq 0$ in order for $\sqrt a$ to be defined. And then we'd need $\sqrt a + b \geq 0 \iff \sqrt a \geq -b$

Answer (score 1):

You ask for the maximal domain of $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{x}}$. For this to be defined you need to have $\sqrt{x} \in [0,2]$ else the 'outer' square-root won't be defined. But $\sqrt{x} \in [0,2]$ is equivalent to $x \in [0,4]$.

Comment: That does not make any sense.

Comment: It makes perfect, perfect, perfect sense.

Comment: Tiny mistake: The outer sqrt is defined for $\sqrt x \in (-\infty, 2]$, which is equivalent to $\sqrt x \in [0,2]$ because $\sqrt\cdot (\mathbb R^+) = \mathbb R^+$, so $(-\infty,0)$ is not in the range.

Comment: Good point @AlexR - thanks :)

Comment: @Utveckla och förenkla: This answer is indeed correct, you should tell us why doesn't it make sense to you so that we can explain it better